# Difference between debug: solr 3.5 and solr 4.1 or higher

Tags: solr

I want upgrade Solr 3.5 to Solr 4.10.3, but I have doubts about the type fieldtype:

**Solr 4.10.3**(code from example):

```xml
<fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true" 
            maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" 
            ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**Solr 3.5** (code from example):

```xml
<fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" 
            enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true" 
            maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"
            ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" 
            enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Solr query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=text_rev%3A*do&wt=xml&indent=true&debugQuery=true
```

**Solr3.5 debug:**

```
'rawquerystring':'text_rev:*do',
'querystring':'text_rev:*do',
'parsedquery':'text_rev:#1;od*',
'parsedquery_toString':'text_rev:#1;od*'
```

**Solr4.10.3 debug:**

```
'rawquerystring':'text_rev:*do',
'querystring':'text_rev:*do',
'parsedquery':'(text_rev:*do)',
'parsedquery_toString':'text_rev:*do',
```

In the Solr 3.5 revers token was used in the query processing ('text_rev:#1;od*'). In the Solr4.10.3 not? Why?